# Error: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType' saving new records Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have some issues trying to save new records in the database, using `model.Autofield`

**`models.py`**:

```
class Proveedor(models.Model):
    id_proveedor = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column='id_proveedor')
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    tipo = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    asignado_a = models.CharField(max_length=15,verbose_name='Asignado a')
    moneda = models.CharField(max_length=1, blank=True)
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'mpc_proveedores'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

**My form**:

```
class ProvForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
       super(ProvForm,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
       self.helper = FormHelper(self)
       self.helper.layout.append(Submit('save','Grabar'))
    class Meta:
       model = Proveedor
```

**My view**:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
def proveedores(request):
    form = ProvForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
       form.save()
       messages.success(request, 'Proveedor Grabado')
       return HttpResponseRedirect('/monitor/')

    return render_to_response("proveedor.html",
                               locals(),
                               context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

When I try  to save the new record I receive the error:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Apparently the form receive the `id_proveedor` empty. I am not sure if is necessary to pass the value in the form definition or in the view definition. And I want to know if is possible save some fields of this form on a another model, without using database triggers.

Any advice?

Comment: Debug the code in terminal. this will actually where you are getting the erro.

Comment: why are you using a custom id column instead of the default one?

Comment: regarding your vague extra question at the end, you can probably avoid needing db triggers by using Django signals https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#module-django.db.models.signals

Comment: maybe your `FormHelper` class is adding the AutoField as a field to the form, but there is no value yet because you are creating a new instance... maybe a bug with FormHelper?

Comment: @danielfranca because it is a legacy database. Believe me I want to create my own database, but that is a long history and I have to use an already created database